# ASAN - Suppressing Reports in External Libraries (LLVM 13, Windows)

Tags: windows, dll, clang, llvm, address-sanitizer

I am trying to suppress ASAN issues in an external library, therefore I am following [llvm-asan-suppressing-reports-in-external-libraries](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html#suppressing-reports-in-external-libraries), the docs says:

> If you run into an issue in external libraries, we recommend immediately reporting it to the library maintainer so that it gets addressed
> Blockquote

*Update*: Here the link to the issue, [Issue 45842: AddressSanitizer: bad-free - hello world c extension - Python tracker](https://bugs.python.org/issue45842)

#### ASAN trace

```
==6968==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: attempting free on address which was not malloc()-ed: 0x01e7aceb3be0 in thread T0
    #0 0x7ffec9a97f31  (D:\a\min_reprex_python_c_extension_asan\min_reprex_python_c_extension_asan\llvm\lib\clang\13.0.0\lib\windows\clang_rt.asan_dynamic-x86_64.dll+0x180037f31)
    #1 0x7ffeca696030  (C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.10.0\x64\python310.dll+0x180026030)
    #2 0x7ffeca67aaaf  (C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.10.0\x64\python310.dll+0x18000aaaf)

...

    #114 0x7ff72208122f  (C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.10.0\x64\python.exe+0x14000122f)
    #115 0x7ffefee17973  (C:\Windows\System32\KERNEL32.DLL+0x180017973)
    #116 0x7fff0071a2f0  (C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll+0x18005a2f0)

Address 0x01e7aceb3be0 is a wild pointer inside of access range of size 0x000000000001.
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: bad-free (D:\a\min_reprex_python_c_extension_asan\min_reprex_python_c_extension_asan\llvm\lib\clang\13.0.0\lib\windows\clang_rt.asan_dynamic-x86_64.dll+0x180037f31) 
==6968==ABORTING
```

[Here](https://github.com/FrancescElies/min_reprex_python_c_extension_asan/runs/4263693010?check_suite_focus=true) a link to the full ASAN trace.

#### What I did so far

I created a `my_asan.supp` and loaded it with `ASAN_OPTIONS=suppressions=my_asan.supp`as suggested in the docs with the following contents:

```
interceptor_via_fun:_PyObject_Realloc
interceptor_via_fun:realloc
interceptor_via_lib:C:/Python39/python3.dll
interceptor_via_lib:C:/s/eklang/DevOps/clang/bin/LLVM-13.0.0-win64/lib/clang/13.0.0/lib/windows/clang_rt.asan_dynamic-x86_64.dll
interceptor_via_lib:C:/Windows/System32/KERNEL32.DLL
interceptor_via_lib:C:/Windows/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll
interceptor_via_lib:C:\Python39\python3.dll
interceptor_via_lib:C:\s\eklang\DevOps\clang\bin\LLVM-13.0.0-win64\lib\clang\13.0.0\lib\windows\clang_rt.asan_dynamic-x86_64.dll
interceptor_via_lib:C:\Windows\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
interceptor_via_lib:C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
interceptor_via_lib:clang_rt.asan_dynamic-x86_64.dll
interceptor_via_lib:ntdll
interceptor_via_lib:ntdll.dll
interceptor_via_lib:python3
interceptor_via_lib:python3.dll
interceptor_via_lib:KERNEL32
interceptor_via_lib:KERNEL32.dll
```

None of these seemed to work, what am I doing wrong? I tried full-path, forward-slash, backslash, dll names ...

#### Info

LLVM 13, Windows 10

Comment: You quoted a big banner up top, telling you what to do. Did you investigate in that direction? Are there existing reports already, possibly even upgrades or patches available? Or is that in your code? In that case, start by extracting a [mcve]. If the error isn't obvious by then, you could add that to your question here.

Comment: As of today llvm 13 is the [latest release](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases), that's the one I am using.

With regards to the banner, see [AddressSanitizer: bad-free - hello world c extension](https://bugs.python.org/issue45842)

The link I already posted above is the [minimal reproducible example](https://github.com/FrancescElies/min_reprex_python_c_extension_asan/runs/4263693010?check_suite_focus=true) you are asking for.

I am not alone here. see [sumatrapdf commit](https://github.com/sumatrapdfreader/sumatrapdf/commit/285a3ae94184e79386c14b6cea64c87d02d5feed)

Comment: Sorry for that, it's just that that info is expected to be inline in the question. Anyhow, in hello.c is a function `hello_system()` without a returntype, which then defaults to `int`. I believe that it's returning a pointer though. At the very least, this indicates that you don't compile with warnings enabled. Am I wrong?

Comment: No problem, I'm glad someone replied :). You are right I am compiling without warnings, but I am sure this is not what is producing the problem though, this is just a reprex, in a real project we are seeing this when loading a dll compiled with asan-rt (that dll is not a c extension in that case).

Comment: In the reprex I am not testing my_asan.supp, that's something I am doing locally, that reprex is only to a showcase for the trace coming from asan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an executable which was not compiled with *asan* (in this case `python.exe`) loads a dll which was compiled with i.

One needs to make sure *asan runtime* is loaded first for it to do it's magic and properly intercept `malloc` and `free`, under linux that's easy, one would use `LD_PRELOAD` (there are many examples in the internet on how to do that).

In windows though, that seems not possible, therefore a workarounds seems to be to make an executable wrapper with `clang_rt.asan-preinit-x86_64.lib` and `clang_rt.asan-x86_64.lib` linked and call python from there, which later on will load the dll needs to be compiled with `clang_rt.asan_dll_thunk-x86_64.lib`.

The whole things sounds quite convoluted but seems to work so far. [This article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/addresssanitizer-asan-for-windows-with-msvc/#contributions-to-asan-runtime)  helped me.